# How to increase string length of artists in Pear PHP - ($id3->getTag('artists'))

Tags: php, pear, id3

How to increase the string length of artists in Pear PHP (`$id3->getTag('artists')`)?

It shows artists: "Jaspreet Jasz, Arjun Chandy, Y"
But artists full name is "Jaspreet Jasz, Arjun Chandy, Yazin Nizar".

```
<?php

$file = "Movie/Tamil/2017/Indrajith/Indrajith/Kbps/Ennenna%20Kaatchigal.mp3";

$r = r($file);
$filesize = filesize($file);
$opis = @file_get_contents('opis/'.$basename.'.txt');

if ($r == 'mp3')
{
    include $mp3;

    $id3 = new MP3_Id();
    $result = $id3->read($file);
    $result = $id3->study();
    $bitrate = $id3->getTag('bitrate') OR $bitrate='';

    if ($id3->getTag('artists'))
    { print 'Artists: '.iconv('windows-1251','UTF-8',$id3->getTag('artists')); }
    // output is "Artists: Jaspreet Jasz, Arjun Chandy, Y".
    // but artist full name "Jaspreet Jasz, Arjun Chandy, Yazin Nizar".

    /****************************/
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the output when you remove the `iconv` conversion? What does `$id3->getTag('artists')` return?

Comment: nothing change, when remove iconv